# Groovy MarkupBuilder code doesn't work in Grails integration

Tags: grails, groovy

I just used the code in groovy site about the markbuilder in my Grails project:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.records() {
  car(name:'HSV Maloo', make:'Holden', year:2006) {
    country('Australia')
    record(type:'speed', 'Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph')
  }
  car(name:'P50', make:'Peel', year:1962) {
    country('Isle of Man')
    record(type:'size', 'Smallest Street-Legal Car at 99cm wide and 59 kg in weight')
  }
  car(name:'Royale', make:'Bugatti', year:1931) {
    country('France')
    record(type:'price', 'Most Valuable Car at $15 million')
  }
}
```

Then I write both unit and integration tests for this in Grails.

However, the unit test pass, but the integration test throws some exception:

```
No such property: car for class: xxxxxxx
Possible solutions: class
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: car for class: xxxxxxx
Possible solutions: class
    at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.closure4_closure16_closure17(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:162)
    at
```

Even I quote the element car, country and record, it still have the same problem.

Comment: I create a new grails project and use the same code the integration test works. But no luck for my work project. Don't know why.

Comment: I said, the test code is exactly the same.